# GA4 Matrix style Exploration

Tags: google-analytics-4

I want to track when users complete and drop out of completing a multi-page form.  I'm capturing the "step" number as the user accesses each step/page in the form via G Tag Manager.  I can see the step values in GA4 Debug (i.e., 1, 2, 3 and 4) so the steps are being collected. I've also created custom dimensions for the column/row headers and a custom metric for the "step_value" to use in reports.  Additionally, the custom metric is set to "Standard".

However, I'm unable to create a meaningful report with the data.

I'd like to see a report similar to below, however, under each step/page the values are always "0" instead of values 1-4.  Is this possible in GA4 or do I need a different tool?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a custom metric.

You need one hit-level custom dimension for the step number, that's it.

In the Explorer, you use event count as a metric, then you use two dimensions: the product name and the step number.

I wouldn't even make the custom dimension. I would use pageviews as a metric and page path or page title as a dimension. Assuming I'm firing pageviews on each step, as I should. Occam's razor. Don't waste custom dimensions and event properties without need.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately, I'm only calling a single page, that hides/unhides different sections to create a multipart form (it's a 3rd party plugin).  I added the Step Values of 1, 2,3,4 because that was the only thing different between the different "pages" of the form.

Comment: Doesn't matter how that page looks from the development standpoint. The only thing that matters is if that feels like a new page to a user. You do not track what your app is doing, you track the customer experience and that's the main point. You could just as well fire pageviews and, if your app does not change the url/title on those page redraws, then just override them in the call by explicitly setting the page_title and page_path

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.  Override where/how?  Are you suggesting custom GA4 triggers or something else?

Comment: no, if you need, you can set page titles, page paths instead of having the library taking them from document automatically. Only in case you need it. I went more in details about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76092606/google-analytics-with-next-js/76093591#76093591 look for `title`. An overridal like this can be done in either, gtag or GTM.